# Excel Cell reference using formula

Tags: algorithms

So lets say I want a repeating sequence of letters "a" through "e" (eg: a,b,c,d,e,a,b,c,d,e) each in separate cells. I set the letters up on a separate sheet on cells A1:A5 I then want to reference them in my first sheet using something similar to A(mod(5,x)) where x is the value of the cell the formula is in... The problem is that I cant seem to figure out how to put formula into the cell reference. How do I put formula into cell references?

Comment: First question in this stack... I'm not certain what may be wrong with this question nor the conventions here but feel free to let me know if there's any misunderstanding.

Comment: You did not ask a question!

Comment: @Moti Question asked... very tired last night...